# How do I make light objects in XNA?

Tags: xna, 2d, graphics, rendering, lighting

Here's my dilemma : I want to have light sources placeable by the player, in terms of lanterns.

I know the best way to do this is to use pixel shaders, which I have done a lot of research and use on, but it seems so far that the lights are static.

So what would be the best method to create a dynamically lit scene?

I already have to workings of a few classes to make 2d lights (Color, Position, Type, Direction, Power) but it is just rendering that is the problem.

Thanks for your considerations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [Deferred Shading](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/DeferredShading.pdf) which is great for rendering scenes with a [large amount of dynamic lights (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvzJ-9ntXMk).

[image]

As for how to implement it, I recommend starting from [here](http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2010/12/28/deferred-rendering-in-xna4-0-source-code/) (courtesy of [Catalin Zima](http://www.catalinzima.com/) and [Roy Triesscheijn](http://www.roy-t.nl)).

Comment: Cool, with a few tweaks I think I can modify this for 2D as well. +1. It's weird I've never come across this blog before, I searched a lot on this topic before posting and this blog never came up once!